# Android Studio GUI Wrong Labels Codification

Tags: android, android-studio, character-encoding

I opened Android Studio yesterday and the GUI is broken .

[image: See Screenshot]

I have been working for several months without problem. I tried to uninstall and install again and nothing happened.

What should I do?

*My configuration:*

- *Windows 10*
- *Android-studio-bundle-141.2288178-windows*

Comment: Try installing a different version of Android Studio and see if that helps you. :) And report this bug to the Android Studio community.

Comment: This has to be the weirdest problem in AS so far. Uninstall the current installation and before installing again, delete these folders from the user folder: _.AndroidStudio1.4_ and the _.gradle_ folders. Also delete the _Android_ folder from Program Files. Hopefully, this fixes the problem. ;-)

Comment: Hi @IceMAN, I did what you said and worked the first time. I closed AS and reopened it and the GUI was broken again.

Comment: @Abhishek solution didnt work either

Comment: I tried to reinstall again and now even in the SDK download the GUI is broken @IceMAN

Comment: @an3sarmiento: In which case, I have no clue. :-(. You might want to scan your computer for viruses though. You should also consider filing a bug report on http://tools.android.com/filing-bugs.